# Strange TimeSpan.ToString output

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

I have a question regarding the symbol that separates days from hours in `TimeSpan.ToString` output.

The standard `TimeSpan` format strings produce different separator symbols:

- "c" produces a period (".") character
- "g" and "G" produce a colon (":") character

Example:

```
// Constant format
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromDays(42).ToString("c", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Output: 42.00:00:00 (period character between days and hours)

// General short format
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromDays(42).ToString("g", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Output: 42:0:00:00 (colon character between days and hours)

// General long format
Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromDays(42).ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Output: 42:00:00:00.0000000 (colon character between days and hours)
```

Does anybody know what's the logic behind it?

However `TimeSpan.Parse` parses all of these string successfully.

Comment: Sometimes you say `TimeSpan` and sometimes you say `DateTime`, is this by mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These characters are hardcoded for those formats.

For [`"c"` standard format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Constant)

```
[-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.fffffff]
```

For [`"g"` standard format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GeneralShort)

```
[-][d:]h:mm:ss[.FFFFFFF]
```

And for [`"G"` Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GeneralLong)

```
[-]d:hh:mm:ss.fffffff
```

Also doc says;

> Unlike the "g" and "G" format specifiers, the "c" format specifier is
>   not culture-sensitive. **It produces the string representation of a
>   TimeSpan value that is invariant and that is common to all previous
>   versions of the .NET Framework before the .NET Framework 4**. "c" is the
>   default TimeSpan format string; the TimeSpan.ToString() method formats
>   a time interval value by using the "c" format string.

Also in [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The .NET Framework does not define a grammar for separators in time
>   intervals. This means that **the separators between days and hours**,
>   hours and minutes, minutes and seconds, and seconds and fractions of a
>   second **must all be treated as character literals** in a format string.

Sounds like the most important reason is *consistency* between all .NET Framework versions. Maybe that's why they call this format as *constant* :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @MaDev Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

There is more detail on [MSDN - Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx).

Essentially:

"c" is the [Constant format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx#Constant): This specifier is not culture-sensitive. Format is **[d’.’]hh’:’mm’:’ss[‘.’fffffff]**

"g" is the [General Short format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx#GeneralShort): This is culture sensitive. Format is **[-][d’:’]h’:’mm’:’ss[.FFFFFFF]**

"G" is the [General Long format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx#GeneralLong): This is culture sensitive. Format is **[-]d’:’hh’:’mm’:’ss.fffffff.**

Comment: I've already read the MSDN documentation. My question was what's the logic behind it...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx#GeneralShort)

> The "g" TimeSpan format specifier returns the string representation of
>   a TimeSpan value in a compact form by including only the elements that
>   are necessary.
>
> [-][d:]h:mm:ss[.FFFFFFF]
>
> .....................
>
> The "c" format specifier returns the string representation of a
>   TimeSpan value in the following form:
>
> [-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.fffffff]

Comment: I've already read the MSDN documentation. My question was what's the logic behind it...